# Compare Varchar to datetime

Tags: sql

I am trying to compare 2 different date formats from 2 tables to find the differences.

- `ListUsersFullInfo` has `DisableDate` like `12/31/2014` (`varchar`)
- `UsersTable` has `EndDate` like `2014-12-31 00:00:00.000` (`datetime`)

I have tried this query but it is not working:

```
SELECT 
    distinct g.[Global User Name], n.EndDate, 'eTDisableDate'
FROM  
    ListUsersFullInfo g 
INNER JOIN
    UsersTable n ON (n.Empid = g.[Employee ID])  
WHERE 
    CONVERT (varchar, (n.EndDate), 101) <> g.DisableDate
```

Any help?

Comment: If you just want to test inequality then convert both to `date` or `varchar` and then compare.

Answer (score 3):

Date takes higher precedence, convert the varchar to date.

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, g.DisableDate, 101) <> n.EndDate
```

Comment: What do you mean by: higher precedence? Thanks

Comment: SQL ranks datatypes datetime being one of the highest.... i.e. when there is a comparison to be made, SQL will implicitly try to convert the lesser precedence to the higher to make the comparison.  More info here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/10/08/sql-server-simple-explanation-of-data-type-precedence/

Comment: I am getting this error when using that where clause:
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: That means there is bad (datetime) data in your varchar date field.. your probably going to need to police your data.. if its not too many rows try to eyeball it.. otherwise write a quick query to move it to a column in temp table and see where it stops at